# Change the backend language of a single plugin

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, translation, language

I'm managing a WordPress installation which main backend language is Italian, mostly due to the needs of the Authors and Editors.

I found a plugin that functionally fits my needs perfectly, but it gets installed with Italian localization by default, which translation of the backend is really poor at the moment to the point of being misleading in some functions.

Is there a way I can keep the admin backend in Italian but show that particular plugin in English?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Are you fluent in Italian to where you can translate?

Comment: To answer your question, yes, I'm native Italian and proficient in English. But the project doesn't allow the time to take on the entire translation file and do it myself. Anyway, what do you suggest?

Comment: I was going to suggest re-writing the translation file for the plugin. Also, contact the plugin author and let them know the Italian translation is not correct. They may fix it for you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but is it evident that the language file was just auto-translated and would need almost complete rehauling. If I'll ever find some time I will certainly help them with the translation. Meanwhile I found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily the plugin developer made two separate file sets, one for frontend and one for backend. So I was able to delete the it-IT backend files, copy the en-US ones and rename the copies as it-IT.

So wordpress thinks it's loading the Italian backend translation while instead the English one gets loaded.

And being frontend and backend separated, nothing changed on the actual site.

Hope this helps someone!